# Select a random file from folder, distribute probability based on name

Tags: php, regex, glob, random

The files are fonts, it's common for them to have names like FontName-type.extension

I have them all together in a single folder, I currently have this function:

```
function random_font($dir = 'fonts')
{
   $fonts = glob($dir . '/*');
   return $fonts[devurandom_rand(0, count($fonts) - 1)];
}
```

The goal is however to get as representative a sample as possible, and fonts that share a FontName are much more similiar to each other than those that don't.

**My problem is selecting a font at random such that fonts that share FontName also share the probability of being selected.**

Answer (score 1):

First, create an array that maps font names to their file paths. For example, your original `$fonts` might be:

```
// You already have this array from the glob function.
$fonts = [
    'Helvetica',
    'Helvetica-Bold',
    'Times New Roman',
]
```

Then, loop through the `$fonts` array to create a `$fontNames` array. The `$fontNames` array maps font names to file names. In this example, the `$fontNames` array would be:

```
$fontNames = [
    'Helvetica' => ['Helvetica', 'Helvetica-Bold'],
    'Times New Roman' => ['Times New Roman'],
];
```

Then, you can choose a random key from `$fontNames` and in turn choose a random value.